# Does Acrobat XI Pro Win ESD support fillable form fields from a CSV?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, adobe-acrobat, csv

At work I had an old version of Adobe Acrobat Pro, version 9, which I used combined with some Actionscript and batch actions to fill in form fields using a csv file and finally outputting to one pdf file per record.

Is this functionality still supported in [Acrobat XI Pro Win ESD](http://www.techsoup.org/products/acrobat-xi-pro-win-esd--G-40959--)?

I would think it would be, but I just thought I would check with some other people and find out as the features listed on the website do not mention that specifically.

Comment: Why not just contact Adobe and ask them?

Comment: On a Friday at 4:00 PM??  Wait what timezone are they in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the source mentioned is indeed legitimate, otherwise I'd suggest to be very careful…

It is possible to import a CSV file and load its contents, do some preprocessing, and loop through it to create documents you want to.

It may require a little bit of understanding of PDF/Acrobat and programming with Acrobat JavaScript, but it is not thaat bad.

The workflow could be simplified if you can provide a tab-delimited format, because there is an Acrobat JavaScript method which can import directly from the file.

Comment: If by the source you're talking about Tech Soup, it's a company for non-profits that helps them get used licenses and hardware.

Comment: Correct; not being in the non-profit environment, I was not aware of that company. I assume that they do have some agreements with Adobe.

Comment: Okay well, last time when I did this in the old version it required the use of a script to do a document merge and it did work.